# Converting gps to gis in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, gps, postgis

I am a little lost on how to do this, I've looked up a bunch of different packages but none of them seemed right. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, in case anyone wants to know, you can just use the confidantes of gps in hasura postgis, it's the same thing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).